# Mysql trying to get best performance in news feed query

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm doing something like news feed on Facebook and I'm using two tables to maintain Posts and Connections:

```
Table Posts:
nId | txCategory_con | nItemid_con | txCategory | nItemid | 
--------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 'user'         | 1           | 'user'     | 1          (posted on user page by user)
2   | 'place'        | 1           | 'user'     | 1          (posted on place page by user)
....

Table Connections:
txCategory | nItemid | nUserid | nActive
------------------------------------------
'place'    | 1       | 1       | 1
```

To get all status update from places, pages, etc that i'm following I used this query:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT(a.nId),
   a.txCategory_con,
   a.nItemid_con,
   a.txCategory,
   a.nItemid,
   a.dtCreated
FROM                    
   Posts a                                        
WHERE                    
 ((SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM Connections b 
   WHERE b.txCategory = a.txCategory_con 
       AND a.nItemid_con = b.nItemid AND b.nUserid = <USERID> AND b.nActive = 1) = 1)
OR (a.txCategory = 'user' AND a.nItemid = <USERID>)
ORDER BY a.dtCreated DESC
LIMIT 0, 5
```

The problem of this query is performance because in 2K rows, the subquery is very slow.

Somebody have others ideas?

Comment: Explain,indexes,kitchen sink.

Comment: To optimize a query, **we need to see the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com ASAP.